# IDEA - display a module in another website

Tags: module, html

I have an HTML website placed in a sub folder of my Joomla website. Is there any way to display a Joomla module in that HTML website?

Comment: Hello and welcome! The only way is using the Webservice API of Joomla but you will need use javascript in your HTML website

Comment: @Carlitorweb how the Javascript hanle this? can you please give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Please, read about how use the endpoints of the API, and how test it with a API client https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/august-2020/joomla-web-services-api-101-tokens,-testing-and-a-taste-test

Then using JS, you can fetch any of this endpoints.

Comment: **TO KNOW:** One of the current authentication the Joomla API use is a token based one. (It also has one for credentials, username and password, but you should always avoid using this one).

As a result, **the core was though and was develop for administration functionality and the idea for the application to interact with itself**. So the Authentication has been designed around that.

I wrote this, because when you fecth, you need explicity write your token in the fetch headers and that will be public inside the page headers.

Comment: Are you wanting to display a Module that you see on your Joomla site in your non-Joomla HTML website as it appears in your Joomla site, as a module? Or is there data/content you are displaying via a Module in your Joomla website and you would like to display that same data/content in your non-Joomla website? Is this a module that you have created or is it a Module that is part of the Joomla core or another extension, if so what is the module you want to display?

Comment: @Carlitorweb although I don't really understand, but I will find out, thank you.

Comment: @Irata This seem exactly what I mean: "Or is there data/content you are displaying via a Module in your Joomla website and you would like to display that same data/content in your non-Joomla website?"
And the module can be a Joomla core module or an extension.

Thanks

Comment: When you access to that site you have in a subfolder, you are out of joomla enviroment, so there is not way you can load anything related to your Joomla site. That is why you need think in a way of ask the data you want trought the API, since I not see another solution for get that data (not the module, the data the module return)

Comment: @Carlitorweb is correct in saying you wont be able to display the Joomla Module and his suggestion has been to get the data you want from the Joomla instance via the API is a good way to get the data. If the data you want is not available via an API then you will need to look at other approaches to get data from the Joomla database. You do need to provide more details in your original post about what the Module on your Joomla site is that you want to display the data from for anyone to be able to help you further, perhaps post an image or  link to show what you have.